# See background image through solid shading in edit mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, image, transparency, wireframe

I am modeling a person's head and face using front and side reference images. I have set the reference images as Background Images for the "Front Ortho" and "Right Ortho" views, respectively. For the most part this is working well except for one odd issue. On the "Front Ortho" view, when I select solid shading mode, the mesh surface shading is semi-transparent, so I can still see the background image behind it. However, when I select solid shading on the "Right Ortho" view, the mesh is fully opaque - so I must switch to wireframe mode to see background image. Aside from the "Axis" and "Source Image", all the Background Image settings are the same between the two. I'm just trying to understand the difference I'm seeing between these two views.

I can see both presentations being useful depending on what you're trying to do/see, so I guess I'm looking for a way I can switch between the two behaviors. For what I'm trying to accomplish right now, I'm mostly interested in being able to see through the mesh in solid mode in "Right Ortho" view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must change the view from *Back* to *Front*. See the screen shot:[image]

You can change to Opacity of the image, if it makes your mesh to hard to see using the slider.

Comment: You know how I said all of the Background Image settings between the two were the same? Well obviously I lied, although I stared at those two settings panels for a good ten minutes and still managed to overlook this. THANK YOU for the helpful (and humbling) tip! :)